# Error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "SELECT Posts.*, Import_Export.* FROM Import_Export INNER JOIN Posts ON Import_Export.CatID = Posts.CatID where Import_Export.Parent=@Parent ";
        if (Request.QueryString["CID"] != null)
        {
            query += " and Import_Export.CatID=@CatID";
            SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = query;
            SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["Parent"].DefaultValue = Request.QueryString["Type"].ToString();
            SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["CatID"].DefaultValue = Request.QueryString["CID"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = query;
            SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["Parent"].DefaultValue = Request.QueryString["Type"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

hi
I write this code and when I run this code below error was occurred:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Why?

Comment: where is your SqlDataSource2 instatiated? Is it meant to be a SqlDataAdapter ?

Comment: @Constanta : in same page that I wrote my code.

Comment: ok well you skipped that bit. Does it look like this SqlDataAdapter SqlDataSource2 = new SqlDataAdapter();

Comment: Error was occurred in this line: `SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["Parent"].DefaultValue = Request.QueryString["Type"].ToString();`

Comment: So where is the parameter "Parent" added. It looks a bit confused I'm wondering if what you are trying to do is adding a new parameter in which case you should do SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("Parent", datatype_goes_here);

Comment: and second part :
SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand.Parameters["Parent"].Value = Request.QueryString["Type"].ToString();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up here's what it should look like

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("Parent", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar);
SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand.Parameters["Parent"].Value =   Request.QueryString["Type"].ToString();
```

OR

```
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Parent",Request.QueryString["Type"].ToString());
```

Comment: I wrote this code and this works :    `SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("Parent", Request.QueryString["Type"].ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "SELECT Posts.*, Import_Export.* FROM Import_Export INNER JOIN Posts ON Import_Export.CatID = Posts.CatID where Import_Export.Parent=@Parent ";
        if (Request.QueryString != null)
        {
            Parameter par = new Parameter("@Parent", DbType.String, Request.QueryString["Type"].ToString());
            SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add(par);


            if (Request.QueryString["CID"] != null)
            {
                query += " and Import_Export.CatID=@CatID";
                SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = query;
                Parameter par2 = new Parameter("@CatID", DbType.String, Request.QueryString["CID"].ToString());
                SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add(par2);
            }
            else
            {
                SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = query;
            }
        }
    }
```